# Proper method for deploying scripts/software to fresh EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Using the AWS SDK, when using the [RunInstances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_RunInstances.html) method to programmatically start up an EC2 instance, what is the proper method for automatically deploying a specific script or setup of software to the instance once it's started? [AWS CodeDeploy](https://aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/)? Or is that overkill?

Essentially I want to:

1. Programmatically start up an On-Demand instance (I got this figured out)
2. After startup, automatically deploy some basic Node.js scripts to the server
3. Automatically execute those scripts.

All of the steps need to be automatic. You can assume the Node.js scripts are in some accessible Git repo hosted somewhere

What is the best and most simple straightforward way to accomplish this?

Comment: There are so many different options for that. Docker, Vagrant, Puppet, Chef, Elastic Beanstalk, Code Deploy, custom shell scripts and so on.

Comment: Obviously I can use stuff like Puppet and Chef to deploy and configure scripts, but how do I get my manifests and recipes on to the instance before firing stuff off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Instance User Data can be a simple script that does that, check out http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html

Comment: Perfect that is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!